# SQL error EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: pandas, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

Error in importing SQL file to pandas (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ZUO.jpg)

```
EOL while scanning string literal
```

I tried to import SQL file stored in my laptop

````
Conn=sqlite3.connect("IMDb.db")
Result=pd.read_sql_query("select * from movie",conn)
```operationalerror
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47wg.jpg)
````

Comment: Replace the `"` after movie. It doesnt look like a normal `"` in your picture.

Comment: Yes , I replaced double quotes with single but now I am getting operational error